# How to use NOT IN or Not Exist custom in Datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, notin

i use 2 table, i want first table not data in table two of show on to database.

**Ex.**
**First Table "filesTA"**

```
EmpNo | ChkDate
00001 | 2012-10-01 00:00:00.000
00001 | 2012-10-02 00:00:00.000
00001 | 2012-10-03 00:00:00.000
00001 | 2012-10-04 00:00:00.000
00001 | 2012-10-05 00:00:00.000
```

**"SalaryDay2"**

```
sEmpNo | sDate
00001 | 2012-10-01 00:00:00.000
00001 | 2012-10-02 00:00:00.000
```

**When i select datetime between 2012-10-01 and 2012-10-05**

**i need output:**

```
sEmpNo | sDate
00001 | 2012-10-03 00:00:00.000
00001 | 2012-10-04 00:00:00.000
00001 | 2012-10-05 00:00:00.000
```

**this code:**

```
SELECT tf.EmpNo,tf.ChkDate
FROM filesTA tf 
WHERE tf.ChkDate NOT IN(
SELECT sd2.sDate
FROM SalaryDay2 sd2
WHERE Convert(nvarchar(10),sd2.sDate,126) Between '2012-10-01' and '2012-10-05'
)
```

**please help me. thanks you for you time.:)**

Comment: Please don't covert `datetime`s into strings. If you need to do a comparison between a string on one side and a `datetime` on the other, please convert the strings into `datetime` values. It may not make much difference in this specific query, but treating dates as strings is one of the biggest sources of date related bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you need something like this:

```
SELECT tf.EmpNo,tf.ChkDate
FROM filesTA tf 
LEFT JOIN SalaryDay2 sd2 ON (sd2.EmpNo = tf.EmpNo AND sd2.ChkDate = tf.ChkDate)
WHERE sd2.EmpNo IS NULL  --you may want to add other condition as well
```

(records from filesTA for which there is no corresponding records in SalaryDay2)

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN` is an inclusive thing, basically boiling down to

```
x BETWEEN a AND b
```

being the same as

```
(x >= a) AND (x <= b)
```

if I'm reading your sample correctly, you want a non-inclusive version, which you'll have to write out the hard way:

```
yourdate > '2012-10-01' AND yourdate <= '2012-10-05'
         ^-- note: <, not <=
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**EXCEPT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clause

```
SELECT EmpNo, ChkDate
FROM filesTA
EXCEPT
SELECT sEmpNo, sDate
FROM SalaryDay2
WHERE sDate BETWEEN '20121001' and '20121005'
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3c80/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this purpose. It should eliminate lines that doesn't exist in your second table, based on your criteria for joining.

```
DECLARE @FirstDate DATE = '2012-10-01'
DECLARE @SecondDate DATE = '2012-10-05'
SELECT  *
FROM    FilesTA
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   SalaryDay2
                     WHERE  SalaryDay2.sDate = FilesTA.ChkDate 
                     -- If you want to check per EmpNo as well uncomment this line:
                     -- AND SalaryDay2.sEmpNo = FilesTA.EmpNo
)
        AND FilesTA.ChkDate BETWEEN @FirstDate
                            AND     @SecondDate
```